# Random walk on a sphere: statistics of the solid angle?

Tags: probability, geometry, spheres, solid-angle

Consider a random path on the surface of a 2-sphere, made of N discrete points (each picked with a uniform distribution across the surface). The path connects two successive points by the shortest line between them, and we connect the last point to the first one to make a closed path.

My question is, what is the statistics of the solid angle subtended by this path? I expect the mean to be zero, but I have no idea for the standard deviation.

Comment: Do we agree that the solid angle is the algebraic area  enclosed by the path ?

Comment: Have you tried simulation ?

Comment: Yes and no respectively, it's a bit nontrivial to code, but I might do it eventually. I'm curious to know how this can be solved analytically though.

Comment: In fact, it is the sum of (signed) areas of spherical triangles for which there is a formula...

Comment: That might be useful, would you have a reference for this?

Answer (score 1):

Here are important tracks. But it's not a complete solution.

As any solid angle is measured by the corresponding area, we need to use the formula for the area of a triangular triangle. Afterwards, there will be a summation process. Let $A,B,C$ be the angles of the triangle, we have

$$area=A+B+C-\pi$$

(angular excess: see Girard's theorem [here](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Erobjohn/math/spheretrig.pdf)).

But we must be able to compute these angles.

This is done by using this formula:

$$\cos c=\cos a\cos b+\sin a\sin b\cos C \ \ \iff \ \ \cos C=\dfrac{\cos c-\cos a\cos b}{\sin a\sin b}$$

and the 2 other formulas obtained by circular permutation:

$$\cos A=\dfrac{\cos a-\cos b\cos c}{\sin b\sin a} \ \ \text{and} \ \ \cos B=\dfrac{\cos b-\cos c\cos a}{\sin c\sin b}$$

When the path $M_1M_2\cdots M_nM_1$ is completed, one computes the sum of areas:

$$\Delta=s_1 \times area(M_1M_2M_3)+ s_2 \times area(M_1M_3M_4)+ \cdots + s_{n-2} \times  area(M_1M_{n-1}M_{n})\tag{1}$$

where the sign $s_k$ is $+$ if the triangle is positively oriented, $-$ otherwise.

(1) defines a random variable.

The mathematical expectation of $\Delta$ is the sum of the mathematical expectations of the triangular areas, which are clearly $0$ because there is a balance between the positive and negative areas.

The variance of $\Delta$, assuming mutual independence between the different areas, is the sum of variances of the triangle's areas:

$$E(area(M_1M_kM_{k+1})^{\color{red}{2}})$$

... which have to be computed by taking into account the variances and expectancies of sides lengths $\cos a, \cos b, \cos c$, themselves functions of the number $N$ of points "dropped" on the sphere, which doesn'tt look very easy to do, because we have to take as well into account the shortest path limitation. But I think rather good approximations can be obtained by taking a uniform enough distribution of points on the sphere.

**Remark:** Given a number $N$ of points on the sphere, set apart exceptional values of $N$, it is not possible to have an even distribution of points on the sphere, for example with $N=5$, but we can get rather close to it.

Comment: That's good tracks indeed, thanks! The distribution of one single triangle area can be found in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.5329.pdf. It leads to a mean and sigma both equal to $\pi/ 2$ (I verified that numerically). So now for a path made of N points, I can decompose as you did in your sum, and assume each triangle independent (not true but... for large N maybe it's OK?). Given the sigma of your s variable is 1, the sigma of the total signed area would be $\pi\sqrt{N/2}$. Still need to verify that numerically (bit more tricky than for a single triangle...).

Comment: I appreciate this exchange. I have had a look at the reference you gave: interesting ! I come back to the way you build your path: do we agree that being in a point, the next point is randomly selected among the $N-1$ other points ?

Comment: See the excellent document [here](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/spheretrig.pdf) by Rob. John that hopefully is the same person as the "RobJohn" who is a regular contributor in MathSE.

Comment: :) I think I understand now what you meant about the uniformity - actually I define a path by a set of N points, where each point is a random point generated with a uniform probability density across the surface of the sphere. There's no predefined set in which I pick them (hope that makes sense...).