# Generalisation of the concept of angle

Tags: geometry, angle

The angle between two vectors is related to the scalar product as
$\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} = |\mathbf{a}| |\mathbf{b}| \cos \gamma $, or the area of the triangle determined by the vectors as $\frac{1}{2}|\mathbf{a}| |\mathbf{b}| \sin \gamma$. I am wondering if there exists a generalisation of the angle concept to three vectors, perhaps using the triple product $(\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b})\cdot\mathbf{c}$?

Comment: In what number of dimensions?

Comment: In two dimensions, the determinant of the matrix whose columns are $a$ and $b$ is the area of the parallelogram with sides $a$ and $b$, which is twice the area of the triangle. In general, in any dimension, the determinant of vectors $v_1,\dots,v_n$ is the volume of the $n$-dimensional "parallelogram" spanned by the vectors. In 3 dimensions, the "triple" product is the same as the determinant.

Comment: I meant in three dimensions.

Comment: The most natural generalisation in 3D is the solid angle which is the area of the spherical triangle defined by unit vectors $a/\|a\|,b/\|b\|,c/\|c\|$ obtained by formulas of spherical geometry as given for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3921421).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the solid angles. Are there specific polynomial associated with solid angles analogous to e.g. Legendre polynomials?